# R igraph plotting a large graph - thresholding?

Tags: r, igraph, threshold

I have a large graph with 60k nodes. The graph is in the form of a distance matrix 60kX60k.

All of these distances are between 0 and 1 -- they are just 1 - cosine similarity.

I want to plot this graph using igraph and use auto thresholding so that large distance nodes do not form edges between them.

What is the best way to do this ?

I did a manual thresholding of 0.1 and removed all edges with distance greater than 0.1. Right now my computer hangs when I try to do this plot. Ideally I want to just specify the number of edges and want igraph to create the plot with the closest nodes within that number of edges..

Thanks a lot..

Comment: You need to include some code. You can use a random graph that is similar to yours. Also, plotting a graph with that many vertices is usually not helpful, unless you simplify the graph by clustering the vertices or some other way.

Answer (score 1):

First, I am a huge fan of the `igraph` package. It has been a lifesaver for me.

That being said, I had a similar problem with plotting large graphs in `rigraph`. My solution was to plot the graph using `plot.default` instead of `plot.igraph`. However, this requires some additional work. Also, if the graph large and the edge-list long, I would try to use `data.table` when transforming the `igraph` object into a rectangular array that can be plotted.

Below is a replicable sample code:

```
library("tictoc")
library("magrittr")
library("igraph")
library("data.table")

set.seed(42)

# no of nodes
n = 2000
# layout
layout = matrix(rnorm(n * 2L), nrow = n)

# sample graph
g = sample_gnp(n, .05)

# plot.igraph
igraph_plot = function() {
    pdf("plot_igraph.pdf")
    plot(
        g, 
        vertex.label = NA, 
        vertex.size = 1.5, 
        vertex.color = "black",
        edge.color = scales::alpha("grey", .3), 
        layout = layout
    )
    dev.off()
}

# plot.default
base_plot = function() {
    
    pdf("plot_base.pdf")
    
    # get edge-list
    el = as.data.table(as_edgelist(g)) %>%
        setnames(c("x","y"))
    
    # add ids to layout
    d_layout = data.table(
        x_coord = layout[, 1L],
        y_coord = layout[, 2L],
        id      = 1:n
    )
    
    # add coordinates to edgelist endpoints
    el_w_layout = merge(
        el, 
        d_layout, 
        by.x = "x",
        by.y = "id",
        all.x = TRUE
    ) %>%
        setnames(
            c("x_coord", "y_coord"), c("x1", "y1")
        ) %>%
        merge(
            d_layout,
            by.x = "y",
            by.y = "id",
            all.x = TRUE
        ) %>%
        setnames(
            c("x_coord", "y_coord"), c("x2", "y2")
        )
    
    # plot frame plot.default
    plot(
        d_layout$x_coord, 
        d_layout$y_coord, 
        axes = F, 
        type = "n", 
        xlab = NA, 
        ylab = NA
    )
    
    # add edges
    segments(
        x0  = el_w_layout$x1,
        x   = el_w_layout$x2,
        y0  = el_w_layout$y1,
        y   = el_w_layout$y2,
        col = scales::alpha("grey", .3)
    )
    # add vertices
    points(d_layout$x_coord, d_layout$y_coord, pch = 19, cex = .5)
    dev.off()
}
```

Running this code gives me:

```
tic()
igraph_plot()
toc()
2.002 sec elapsed
```

and

```
tic()
base_plot()
toc()
0.277 sec elapsed
```